# Android - CountDownTimer on DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

So, I created a create a button the will pop up an alert dialog with radio button items are 5 , 10 , 15 mins and when I select the item the countdowntimer will start based on the mins selected and my problem now is how to stop the timer with another button.

SO I HAVE 2 CLASS:

Start.java

```
public class Start extends DialogFragments{
CountDownTimer timer1;
//The rest of the code
}
```

Stop.java

```
public class Stop extends DialogFragments{
@onCreateDialog
AlertDialog ........
@setPositive.......
// here I want to call the timer to be cancel;
}
```

Im new in android environment so I want to cancel/stop the timer when I clicked the OK in the alertdialog in stop fragment

Comment: Posting some code will be better so that we can see what you have done so far. Anyway you can call yourTimer.cancel(); to stop a countdownTimer.

Answer (score 1):

keep a reference in the activity or fragment for your CountDownTimer and use yourCountDownTimer.cancel() to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

On each tick you can update your textview
use your coustom timming and enjoy!

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```